# Meaning of the word "certifications" in "our ability to implement and maintain best-in-class security solutions and certifications"

Tags: word-meaning

From a booklet issued by a company that promotes its cloud computing services to potential clients:

> Many customers’ security posture actually improves when they move to the cloud. In the cloud, you have have a better look into the state of all your infrastructure. Our customers benefit from our ability to implement and maintain best-in-class security solutions and **certifications**.

Does it mean that their security solutions receive certificates, and that the company maintains these certificates through regular testing?

Or does it mean that the company's staff earns certificates in the cloud security sphere by attending education courses?

Comment: It could mean what you suggest, or it could mean that the solutions implemented can be certified as a guarantee that they conform to a recognised standard. Edit: I've just realised that that is your first suggestion.

Comment: http://www.darkreading.com/risk/10-security-certifications-to-boost-your-career/d/d-id/1322449

Comment: Here's a list of certifications you can earn: https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/cloud-certifications

Comment: @Lambie - you think this does relate to the company's staff having certification documents earned? Why then "implement and maintain"?

Comment: @CowperKettle Yes, but there is also ISO certification where the company is certified rather than the individual technicians/engineers. To implement security solutions and maintain certifications, respectively. They forgot the word respectively. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the term "certification" here is a little odd, as it's normally applied to people and not systems.  I'm not familiar with the "certifications" they mean -- it sounds more like they're saying their systems are better able to maintain proper compliance with security standards so they can pass a [security audit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology_security_audit).

Passing a security audit might grant a *certification of compliance*, but I can't seem to easily find details on this.  [This page regarding Google Cloud's security compliance](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance) might offer more information.